# Use a string variable inside an if condition in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem in twig which is below :

I want to use a variable which is a string which is a condition ( that i read from a table from a yml file) inside and if statement consider this example.

```
{% set condition = 'a condition' %}
{% if condition == true ]%
do something
{% endif %}
```

Notice : the string used as a variable contains a twig code

How is it possible to do that ??

is there any similar to eval() of php in twig ?

thanx in advance

Comment: Why can't you calculate that condition in PHP and pass it to Twig as a boolean variable?

Comment: Notice : the string used as a variable contains a twig

Answer (score 1):

You can use some tricky hack with `is_granted` function. It's created to be used for security purposes but it will work for your use case.

`is_granted` can evaluate Symfony Expressions, then result can be used in conditional statements.

This example works fine for your case:

```
{% set condition = "true" %}
{% if is_granted(expression(condition)) %}
    CONDITION IS TRUTHY
{% endif %}
```

To make it work you need to install symfony-expressions and security components:

```
composer require symfony/expression-language
composer require security
```

Also if you don't use it for granting access for users to some places in your template it would be better to create own twig function that will execute Symfony Expressions like `is_granted` do.